# How can I calculate the convergence of summations in this form?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

I'm not sure how to start evaluating these. I feel Taylor Series' may help, but I don't really know how to start:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k)}{k!}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\tan(k)}{k!}\\
$$
Obviously, the $k!$ in the denominator has me thinking $e$, but I'm not sure what I would do precisely. It'd be awesome if you would try to show me how at least one of these is calculated as an example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending of $f(k)$ some series will converge an other diverge. And doesnt exists a standard way to evaluate all convergent series of this form.

Comment: EDIT: @Masacroso can you show me how to evaluate the top two expressions?

Comment: My calculator got $\sin(\sin(1))\cdot e^{\cos(1)}$.

Comment: The series with sine function seems possible to simplify and evaluate manually cause it relatively [simple value](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BSin%5Bk%5D%2Fk!,%7Bk,0,oo%7D%5D). But the series with the tangent seems [very far to some easy evaluation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+(tan(k))%2F(k!)&lk=2) by hand.

Comment: For the first sum, you can simply utilize the representation $$ \sin k = \frac{e^{ik} - e^{-ik}}{2i}, $$ which readily yields $e^{\cos 1}\sin \sin 1$. For the second series, though, I don't see any simple answer to this. Even the convergence of the series is not easy to establish (as you have to appeal to the fact that $\pi$ has finite irrationality measure).